# How to detect if data class overrided equals in kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

Say I have a reference to a data class in kotlin-jvm. How do I determine if this `KClass` did override equals?

With non-data classes, this can be determined with `kClass.java.getMethod("equals", Any::class.java).delcaringClass == Any::class.java`. However, with data classes the result of this operation is the same regardless if the author of the data class did explicitly override equals.

Comment: Why do you need to find it?

Comment: @MattGroth For data classes the compiler creates equals, hashCode, etc. implicitly. So they are always present on each data class you create. See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html.

Comment: I'm generating python code that mirrors some behavior of some kotlin code. Perhaps this one isn't possible from bytecode/reflection alone.

Answer (score 0):

Using IDEA's Kotlin bytecode viewer, it seems auto-generated `equals` implementations lack `LINENUMBER`, which makes sense. But that's not exposed in the reflection API.

There's also two extra lines

```
// annotable parameter count: 1 (visible)
// annotable parameter count: 1 (invisible)
```

on the manual implementation, though I'm not sure what those mean. `func.parameters` is identical.